# Typeorm: Check if a property is either value 1, 2, 3 or n

Tags: repository, filtering, querying, typeorm

I want to get all tasks that have a certain `role`. I have an array of strings for which I want to get the tasks.

Query:

```
return this.createQueryBuilder('task')
    .select(this.baseSelect)
    .where('task.role = :role', { role }) // What here?
    .getMany();
```

This code of course only gets the tasks for which the role is that one value.
How can I check multiple values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For searching in multiple roles you can use the IN operator:

*OLD VERSION of TypeORM*

```
return this.createQueryBuilder('task')
    .select(this.baseSelect)
    .where('task.role IN(:roles)', {roles: [role1, role2, role3]});
    .getMany();
```

*NEW VERSION of TypeORM*

As mentioned by user Christophe Geers, In the new version, you will have to use the spread syntax.

```
return this.createQueryBuilder('task')
    .select(this.baseSelect)
    .where('task.role IN(:...roles)', {roles: [role1, role2, role3]});
    .getMany();
```

Comment: In newer versions you'll have to use the spread syntax.
...where('task.role IN(:...roles)', { roles: [role1, role2, role3]});

Reference: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1239